# Updating specific XML elements in C#

Tags: c#, xml

I am building a game in C# which will store multiple user's data in an XML file.  I am having trouble figuring out how to update XML data for only the current player (e.g. Jack):

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PlayerStats>
  <Name>Jack</Name>
  <WinCount>15</WinCount>
  <PlayCount>37</PlayCount>

  <Name>John</Name>
  <WinCount>12</WinCount>
  <PlayCount>27</PlayCount>
</PlayerStats>
```

The  element in the XML file should match a string variable "strPlayerName" from C# (Jack).  Then, only Jack's WinCount and PlayCount numbers should be updated.

How can I match the  element with the strPlayerName string variable and then update the  and  numbers in the XML doc for only this player?  Thanks,

Comment: Well, what have you already tried? I'd strongly recommend using LINQ to XML where possible. Also, can you change the XML structure at all? There are much simpler structures you could use - having repeated "sets" of elements like this is generally painful. Having a `<Player>` element either with nested Name/WinCount/PlayCount elements or with those as attributes would make it easier to work with.

Comment: Yes, a structure like `<PlayerStats><Player><Name>A</Name><WinCount>2</WinCount></Player><Player><Name>B</Name><WinCount>3</WinCount></Player></PlayerStats>`. @JonSkeet If you don't mind me asking, could you give a simple explanation why you strongly recomment LINQ to XML? I know it's really popular here on SO, but most of the LINQ to XML code I see here just looks hideous compared to `XmlNode.Select()` with a clean line of XPath.

Comment: I don't really see why you wouldn't just write a class to hold the data and simply serialise it?

Comment: @JLRishe: You say "clean" I say "really easy to mess up and only find out at execution time" :) With LINQ to XML it's extremely simple (and reliable) to see which bit of your code means "look for an element", which bit means "look for an attribute" etc. And I can use all the query operators (Any, All, Where etc) that I use when performing queries on *other* data sources. I dislike "nested" languages in general - using one language inside another usually suffers from poor tooling etc.

Comment: Im very new to XML and a c# beginnger so I can definitely change the XML schema.  What I have tried is almost irrelevant because so far ive only been able to read all the PlayerStats elements into C# using SelectSingleNode.  I'm trying to learn XML so thats why I am using an XML file.

Comment: @JonSkeet Thanks for the explanation. I guess LINQ to XML does better fit the strongly-typed notions of C# and other .NET languages, and it's much safer for string-matching than `XmlNode`'s XPath API, but gosh does it get verbose really quickly!

Comment: @JLRishe: Yes, it's definitely more verbose than XPath. But sometimes being verbose *adds* to readability rather than detracting from it.

Comment: +1 to serializing/deserializing this into an object - much easier than dealing with LINQ to XML or XPath if your XML structure really is this simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your XML structure to be as follows:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<PlayerStats>
    <Player>
        <Name>Jack</Name>
        <WinCount>15</WinCount>
        <PlayCount>37</PlayCount>
    </Player>

    <Player>
        <Name>John</Name>
        <WinCount>12</WinCount>
        <PlayCount>27</PlayCount>
    </Player>
</PlayerStats>
```

Create some classes to hold your XML data:

```cs
[XmlRoot("PlayerStats")]
public class PlayerStats
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Player")]
    public List<Player> Players { get; set; }
}

public class Player
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int WinCount { get; set; }
    public int PlayCount { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can do the following to read it, update and re-write the file.

```cs
PlayerStats stats;
using (var fileStream = new System.IO.FileStream("Sample.XML", System.IO.FileMode.Open))
{
    XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(PlayerStats));
    stats = (PlayerStats)xmlSerializer.Deserialize(fileStream);
}

var player = stats.Players.Where(p => p.Name == "Jack").FirstOrDefault();
if (player != null)
{
    // Update the record
    player.WinCount = player.WinCount + 1;
    player.PlayCount = player.PlayCount + 1;

    // Save back to file
    using (var fileStream = new System.IO.FileStream("Sample.XML", System.IO.FileMode.Create))
    {
        XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(PlayerStats));
        xmlSerializer.Serialize(fileStream, stats);
    }
}
```

Comment: This code is actually causing some bizarre corruption in the XML file.  After I add a new player and attempt to append data to the XML file, an extra tag "</PlayerStats>yer>" gets added to the file...haven't figured out why yet.

Comment: The file mode in which the file is being opened during writing is not correct.  Change to FileMode.Create and it will empty the file before writing.  The current mode does not empty the file before writing.  I have updated the code above.

Comment: What if you had an additional element outside 'Player Stats' ? I've got a similar situation, and i'm confused by the fact that the XML i'm working with (from a separate app) starts with one element 'Trebuchet' , and then goes on to hold a 'connectiondeflist' with many 'connectiondef' elements in it. I'm a newb when it comes to XML in .NET ; how would you go about adding an additional outer element to this structure?

Comment: @DougRobinson An answer to your question would be too involved for a comment. Best for you to ask it as a new StackOverflow question.

Answer (score 1):

As Matthew Watson recommended, a good solution would be using XML and Serialization.

Create an xml in your project and make sure its properties are set to none for Build Action and Copy Always or Copy if Newer for Copy to Output Directory.

Here is an example of the xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ArrayOfPlayer xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Player>
    <Name>Jack</Name>
    <WinCount>15</WinCount>
    <PlayCount>37</PlayCount>
  </Player>
  <Player>
    <Name>John</Name>
    <WinCount>12</WinCount>
    <PlayCount>27</PlayCount>
  </Player>
</ArrayOfPlayer>
```

Now we will use this XML to deserialize it into a List of Players. I have a helper class for serialization below. You would read the XML file contents and pass it to the Deserialize method as shown. When you wish to save the Players list, pass the list to Serializer and save back to your file.

Serializer helper class:

```
public static class Serializer
{
    public static string SerializeObject(object objectToSerialize)
    {
        XmlSerializer x = new XmlSerializer(objectToSerialize.GetType());

        StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
        x.Serialize(writer, objectToSerialize);

        return writer.ToString();
    }

    public static T DeserializeObject<T>(string serializedObject)
    {
        XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
        StringReader reader = new StringReader(serializedObject);
        return (T)xs.Deserialize(reader);
    } 
}
```

Using the class to Deserialize:

```
//Change this as needed to read your XML file. 
string playersXML = File.ReadAllText(@"./Players.xml");
List<Player> players = Serializer.DeserializeObject<List<Player>>(playersXML);
```

Using the class to serialize and save the list:

```
string newPlayersXML = Serializer.SerializeObject(players);
//Change this as needed to point to the XML location
File.WriteAllText(@"./Players.xml", newPlayersXML);
```

And finally the Player class:

```
public class Player
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int WinCount { get; set; }
    public int PlayCount { get; set; }
}
```

You would use your Player class and the list as you need in the code.

Comment: I tried your code but I couldn't figure out how to get the List<Player> players = Serializer.DeserializeObject<List<Player>>(playersXML);
line to work (kept throwing errors).  I used other code but im sure what you wrote works, I am just still learning C#.

Answer (score 0):

Supposing your XML file looked like this:

```
<PlayerStats>
  <Player>
    <Name>Jack</Name>
    <WinCount>15</WinCount>
    <PlayCount>37</PlayCount>
  </Player>
  <Player>
    <Name>John</Name>
    <WinCount>12</WinCount>
    <PlayCount>27</PlayCount>
  </Player>
</PlayerStats>
```

Here's how you could update John's stats using the `XmlNode` API:

```
string name = "John";

XmlNode player = doc.SelectNodes("/PlayerStats/Player")
                    .OfType<XmlNode>()
                    .FirstOrDefault(n => n["Name"].InnerText == name);

if (player != null)
{
    player["WinCount"].InnerText = "21";
    player["PlayCount"].InnerText = "22";
}
```

or with LINQ to XML:

```
var player2 = xe.Descendants("Player")
                .FirstOrDefault(n => (string)n.Element("Name") == name);

if (player != null)
{
    player2.Element("WinCount").SetValue(21);
    player2.Element("PlayCount").SetValue(22);
}
```

Though as others have said, for a task like this, serializing, deserializing is probably the way to go.

Comment: Which assembly references and/or using statements are required for this code? Sometimes it's not obvious.

Comment: If you place the cursor on an unresolved class name and press Alt+Shift+F10, VS will generally tell you what using statement you need, but both require `using System.Linq;`, the first requires `using System.Xml;` and the second requires `using System.Xml.Linq;`. The assemblies needed for this are generally included by default in any VS project, but the first one requires `System.Xml`, and the second requires `System.Xml.Linq`.

Comment: Thanks! I only asked for the namespaces for historical purposes in case someone else needed to know. Also, `Ctrl+.` is far easier than `Alt+Shift+F10`. ;)

Comment: @SpikeX Awesome. I will definitely use that from now on.